# JavaScript Popup in Ruby on Rails that loads data on current page and changes the URL, like Pinterest

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I want to create a JavaScript popup on a current page so when a link is clicked it opens the popup, loads the data, and displays it, and changes the URL without refreshing the page so the back button still works. I'm using ruby on rails and jQuery.

I'm not exactly sure of the whole process to get this to work. I'd also like the popup to have a loading animated gif (I already have the image itself) until the contents of the popup are loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to [pjax gem](https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax). I think it's gem special for you :)